# subprocess.Popen("top | grep -i lsd",shell = True)

Tags: python, process, subprocess, pid, tty

I have created a python script which starts a bash script for my work. I need to know the status of the process using top command and print "Finished" when its over. I have tried to achieve the same using subprocess command.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("top | grep -i lsd",shell=True)
poll =p.poll()
while poll == None:
    p = subprocess.Popen("top  | grep -i lsd", shell=True)
    poll = p.poll()
print("Done")
```

Its working fine, but getting an additional error message from top.
top: failed tty get
top: failed tty get
top: failed tty get
top: failed tty get
top: failed tty get
top: failed tty get
Done
ps -ef is not working in my case, as the server is a cluster server and lsd process will be running on it all the time. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: You could add "-b" for batch mode so that top doesn't care about a controlling tty.

Comment: I have tried top -b | grep -i lsd . But the program is hanging out there without showing any error message. How Can I overcome this issue?